# How to make list of list from dataframe pandas?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a Pandas dataframe with words and tags

```
  words   tags
0 I       WW
1 am      XX
2 newbie  YY
3 .       ZZ
4 You     WW
5 are     XX
6 cool    YY
7 .       ZZ
```

Is there any method on how do I create list of list from the dataframe something like this:

```
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.','ZZ')], 
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.','ZZ')]]
```

It is a list of lists of tuples. For each list inside the list are separated by `('.','ZZ')`. Mean that it is a sentence.

I can iterate on each rows of dataframe and create list and append it if the condition is true, but is there any 'pandas' way to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first create tuples from all values and then separate them to sublists if performance is important:

```
from  itertools import groupby

L = list(zip(df['words'], df['tags']))
print (L)
[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), 
 ('.', 'ZZ'), ('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), 
 ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]

sep = ('.','ZZ')
new_L = [list(g) + [sep] for k, g in groupby(L, lambda x: x==sep) if not k] 
print (new_L)

[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')], 
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

def zero(df):
    dft = df.apply(tuple, 1)
    return ([x.values.tolist() for _, x in dft.groupby((dft == ('.', 'ZZ')).shift().cumsum().bfill())])

In [55]: %timeit ([list(g) + [('.','ZZ')] for k, g in groupby(list(zip(df['words'], df['tags'])), lambda x: x==('.','ZZ')) if not k] )
100 loops, best of 3: 4.14 ms per loop

def pir(df):
    v = df.values
    return ([list(map(tuple, x)) for x in np.split(v, np.where((v == ['.', 'ZZ']).all(1)[:-1])[0] + 1)])

In [68]: %timeit (pir(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ms per loop


In [56]: %timeit (zero(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 328 ms per loop

In [57]: %timeit (df.groupby((df.shift().values == ['.', 'ZZ']).all(axis=1).cumsum()).apply(lambda group: list(zip(group['words'], group['tags']))).values.tolist())
1 loop, best of 3: 286 ms per loop

In [58]: %timeit (list(filter(None,[i.apply(tuple,1).values.tolist() for i in np.array_split(df,df[(df['words'] == '.') & (df['tags'] == 'ZZ')].index+1)])))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.31 s per loop
```

For separate to sublists I create question, you can check solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46500077/2901002):

```
def jez_coldspeed(df):
    L = list(zip(df['words'], df['tags']))
    L2 = []
    for i in L[::-1]:
        if i == ('.','ZZ'):
            L2.append([])

        L2[-1].append(i)

    return [x[::-1] for x in L2[::-1]]

def jez_coldspeed1(df):
    L = list(zip(df['words'], df['tags']))
    L2 = []
    sep = ('.','ZZ')
    for i in reversed(L):
         if i == sep:
             L2.append([])

         L2[-1].append(i)

    return [x[::-1] for x in reversed(L2)]


In [74]: %timeit (jez_coldspeed(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.96 ms per loop

In [75]: %timeit (jez_coldspeed1(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
```

---

```
def jez_theBuzzyCoder(df):
    L = list(zip(df['words'], df['tags']))
    a = list()
    start = 0
    sep = ('.', 'ZZ')

    while start < len(L) and (L.index(sep, start) != -1):
        end = L.index(sep, start) + 1
        a.append(L[start:end])
        start = end
    return a


print (jez_theBuzzyCoder(df))

In [81]: %timeit (jez_theBuzzyCoder(df))
100 loops, best of 3: 3.16 ms per loop
```

Comment: This method is definitely fastest.

Comment: Very fast indeed.

Comment: Aha! Fast indeed!

Comment: Wow! Mindblown. Thanks everyone! (especially for you jezrael xD)

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way

```
In [5149]: dft = df.apply(tuple, 1)

In [5150]: parts = (dft == ('.', 'ZZ')).shift().cumsum().bfill()
           # parts = (dft.shift() == ('.', 'ZZ')).cumsum()       from Alexander's

In [5151]: [x.values.tolist() for _, x in dft.groupby(parts)]
Out[5151]:
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Or,

```
In [5152]: dft.groupby(parts).apply(list).tolist()
Out[5152]:
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Or,

```
In [5165]: list(dft.groupby(parts).apply(list))
Out[5165]:
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

---

Details

```
In [5153]: parts
Out[5153]:
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    0.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
7    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do np.array_split i.e

```
li = list(filter(None,[i.apply(tuple,1).values.tolist() \
     for i in np.array_split(df,df[(df['words'] == '.') & (df['tags'] == 'ZZ')].index+1)]))
```

or

```
x = df.apply(tuple,1)
li = [ i.tolist() for i in np.array_split(x,x[x==('.','ZZ')].index+1) if len(i.tolist())>1]
```

Output:

```
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
v = df.values

[
    list(map(tuple, x))
    for x in np.split(v, np.where((v == ['.', 'ZZ']).all(1)[:-1])[0] + 1)
]

[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part (`df.groupby((df.shift().values == ['.', 'ZZ']).all(axis=1).cumsum())`) will group the dataframe on contiguous values in the 'words' column of the dataframe up to and including a period where the second column also equals `Z`.  This is a variation of the `shift-cumsum` pattern (search pandas shift cumsum on SO and you should find many variations).

The second part (`.apply(lambda group: zip(group['words'], group['tags']))`) creates tuple pairs for each row, e.g.

```
0     [(I, WW), (am, XX), (newbie, YY), (., ZZ)]
1    [(You, WW), (are, XX), (cool, YY), (., ZZ)]
dtype: object
```

The final part (`.values.tolist()`) converts the dataframe to your desired format as a list of lists.

```
>>> df.groupby((df.shift().values == ['.', 'ZZ']).all(axis=1).cumsum()).apply(
        lambda group: zip(group['words'], group['tags'])).values.tolist()
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')],
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Comment: I think, Alex went with the assumption that since these are NLP tags, `'.'` will always be tagged to `'ZZ'`.

Comment: But I modified it to account for the specific requirement.