# Split list by tuple separator

Tags: python, list, tuples, separator

I have list:

```
print (L)
[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ'), 
 ('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]
```

I want split list to sublists with separator `('.', 'ZZ')`:

```
print (new_L)
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')], 
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

I am interested about another possible solutions, performance is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for-loop approach will be faster, this requires only one-pass:

```
>>> def juan(L, sep):
...     L2 = []
...     sub = []
...     for x in L:
...         sub.append(x)
...         if x == sep:
...             L2.append(sub)
...             sub = []
...     if sub:
...         L2.append(sub)
...     return L2
...
>>> juan(L, sep)
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')], [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

Some comparisons:

```
>>> def jezrael(L, sub):
...     return [list(g) + [sep] for k, g in groupby(L, lambda x: x==sep) if not k]
...
>>> def coldspeed(L, sep):
...     L2 = []
...     for i in reversed(L):
...         if i == sep:
...             L2.append([])
...         L2[-1].append(i)
...     return [x[::-1] for x in reversed(L2)]
...
>>> def pm2ring(L, sep):
...     seplist = [sep]
...     return [list(g) + seplist for k, g in groupby(L, sep.__eq__) if not k]
...
>>> setup = "from __main__ import L, sep, juan, coldspeed, pm2ring, jezrael"
```

#### Edit: more timings

```
>>> def buzzycoder(L, sep):
...     a = []
...     length = len(L)
...     start = 0
...     end = L.index(sep)
...     if start < length: a.append(L[start:end+1])
...     start = end + 1
...     while start < length:
...         end = L.index(sep, start) + 1
...         a.append(L[start:end])
...         start = end
...     return a
...

>>> def splitList(l, s):
...     ''' l is list, s is separator, simular to split, but keep separator'''
...     i = 0
...     for _ in range(l.count(s)): # break using slices
...         e = l.index(s,i)
...         yield l[i:e+1] # sublist generator value
...         i = e+1
...     if e+1 < len(l): yield l[e+1:] # pick up
...

>>> def bharath(x,sep):
...     n = [0] + [i+1 for i,j in enumerate(x) if j == sep]
...     m= list()
...     for first, last in zip(n, n[1:]):
...         m.append(x[first:last])
...     return m
...
```

And the results:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("jezrael(L, sep)", setup)
4.1499102029483765
>>> timeit.timeit("pm2ring(L, sep)", setup)
3.3499899921007454
>>> timeit.timeit("coldspeed(L, sep)", setup)
2.868469718960114
>>> timeit.timeit("juan(L, sep)", setup)
1.5428746730322018
>>> timeit.timeit("buzzycoder(L, sep)", setup)
1.5942967369919643
>>> timeit.timeit("list(splitList(L, sep))", setup)
2.7872562300181016
>>> timeit.timeit("bharath(L, sep)", setup)
2.9842335029970855
```

With a bigger list:

```
>>> L = L*100000
>>> timeit.timeit("jezrael(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
3.3555950550362468
>>> timeit.timeit("pm2ring(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
2.337177241919562
>>> timeit.timeit("coldspeed(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
2.2037084710318595
>>> timeit.timeit("juan(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
1.3625159269431606
>>> timeit.timeit("buzzycoder(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
1.4375156159512699
>>> timeit.timeit("list(splitList(L, sep))", setup, number=10)
1.6824725979240611
>>> timeit.timeit("bharath(L, sep)", setup, number=10)
1.5603888860205188
```

#### Caveat

The results do not address performance given the proportion of `sep` in `L`, which will affect timings a lot for some of these solutions.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you add theBuzzyCoder solution to timings?

Comment: Time is no problem, I would like wait with accepting, because it stop posting new solutions.

Comment: @jezrael added a bunch of timings

Comment: Sir still a beginner. This is fastest yet +1 :).

Comment: I knew that reversal was not necessary. I was trying to strike a balalnce between speed and elegance. I knew how it would look - it would look exactly like yours does.

Comment: I knew reversal would reduce the function size considerably, while still letting me enjoy the speed of a loop. Frankly I prefer reversal to the monstrosity here, but that’s just the perfectionist in me ;-)

Comment: I accept your answer because - 1.fastest, 2.all timings 3. Caveat

Answer (score 4):

A vanilla `for` loop should be faster than a `groupby`.

```
L2 = []
for i in L[::-1]:
     if i == ('.','ZZ'):
         L2.append([])

     L2[-1].append(i)

L2 = [x[::-1] for x in L2[::-1]]
```

A small tweak (may/may-not improve performance - but is more memory efficient) involves the use of `reversed`:

```
L2 = []
sep = ('.','ZZ')
for i in reversed(L):
     if i == sep:
         L2.append([])

     L2[-1].append(i)

L2 = [x[::-1] for x in reversed(L2)]
```

Another improvement is to reduce the `L[-1]` reference using another reference:

```
cache = []
L2 = cache
sep = ('.','ZZ')
for i in reversed(L):
     if i == sep:
         cache = []
         L2.append(cache)

     cache.append(i)

L2 = [x[::-1] for x in reversed(L2)]
```

---

### Performance

**Small**

```
len(L)
8
```

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.11 µs per loop   # groupby
```

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.54 µs per loop   # loop
```

**Large**

```
len(L)
800000
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 435 ms per loop    # groupby
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 310 ms per loop    # PM 2Ring's groupby
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 250 ms per loop    # loop
1 loop, best of 3: 235 ms per loop    # loop w/ reverse
```

Comment: Maybe for large `L` should be `L = L * 100000` ?

Comment: @jezrael Added. Let me know if a bigger test sample is required.

Comment: `reversed` is usually faster than `[::-1]`, especially if the sequence is large.

Comment: You can go 20% faster by maintaining a reference to the empty list you create (avoiding `L2[-1]`) and using the in-place `.reverse()` method.

Comment: @Blender I find a .15 microsecond improvement on small data, but see no visible difference on larger data.

Comment: There's no need to reverse.

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks OK to me, but you can speed it up a little by getting rid of that `lambda`, eg

```
groupby(L, sep.__eq__)
```

Not only is the code shorter, it saves the overheads of creating the lambda function, and the relatively slow Python function call.

You could also build `[sep]` outside the loop, that might save a few microseconds. ;)

```
from  itertools import groupby

L = [('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ'), 
    ('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]

sep = ('.','ZZ')
seplist = [sep]
new_L = [list(g) + seplist for k, g in groupby(L, sep.__eq__) if not k] 
for row in new_L:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]
[('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]
```

Comment: `1 loop, best of 3: 310 ms per loop`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well, at least my code _is_ noticeably faster than the original. ;) But I'm not surprised that yours is even faster. `groupby` is pretty good, but it's built for versatility, not for speed. And I guess there's also significant overhead in converting the output groups to lists with `list(g)` and concatenating them with `[sep]`.

Comment: My comment was only to alert you to the fact that I measured the performance for you :-)

Answer (score 3):

My solution is:

```
from  itertools import groupby

sep = ('.','ZZ')
new_L = [list(g) + [sep] for k, g in groupby(L, lambda x: x==sep) if not k] 
print (new_L)
[[('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')], 
 [('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]]
```

But I believe better / faster solutions exist too.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = list()
start = 0
while start < len(l) and (l.index(sep, start) != -1):
    end = l.index(sep, start) + 1
    a.append(l[start:end])
    start = end
```

This would be my solution. It is simple and readable.

Comment: Seems to be the fastest solution. The `l.index()` call is the slowest part, so avoiding calculating it twice will make it even faster.

Comment: You can avoid calculating it twice. I didn't go deeper into optimisation

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with enumerate and creating pair with zip i.e

```
def bharath(x,sep):
    n = [0] + [i+1 for i,j in enumerate(x) if j == sep]
    m= list()
    for first, last in zip(n, n[1:]):
        m.append(x[first:last])
    return m

%%timeit
bharath(L,('.','ZZ'))
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.74 µs per loop
L = L*100000
bharath(L,('.','ZZ'))
1 loop, best of 3: 240 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is a great solution if you expect the proportion of `sep` to be low

Answer (score 1):

Using generator and slice is very fast:

```
def splitList(l, s): 
    ''' l is list, s is separator, simular to split, but keep separator'''
    i = 0
    for _ in range(l.count(s)): # break using slices
        e = l.index(s,i)
        yield l[i:e+1] # sublist generator value
        i = e+1
    if e+1 < len(l): yield l[e+1:] # pick up any list left over

l = [('I', 'WW'), ('am', 'XX'), ('newbie', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ'), 
     ('You', 'WW'), ('are', 'XX'), ('cool', 'YY'), ('.', 'ZZ')]    
print(list(splitList(l, ('.', 'ZZ'))))
```

You can also use with other lists and separators.

```
l = ['tom','dick','x',"harry",'x','sally','too']
print(list(splitList(l, 'x')))
```